# Cannot instantiate the type Duration - Joda Java

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to calculate the difference between two dates. This is my code:

```
DateTime today = new DateTime();
DateTime yesterday = today.minusDays(1);

Duration duration = new Duration(yesterday, today);
```

Unfortunately I can't run the above code. Before I run it, I get this error in eclipse:

```
 Cannot instantiate the type Duration
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: @PM77-1 `DateTime` is a `ReadableInstant`.

Comment: @yasuo, Can you post here what the import statement of `Duration` is in your code?

Comment: @RealSkeptic - [Right you are](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud use org.joda.time.Duration class.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Duration;

DateTime today = new DateTime();
DateTime yesterday = today.minusDays(1);

Duration duration = new Duration(yesterday, today);
System.out.println(duration.getStandardDays());
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @ RealSkeptic  I think it is better answer. Why we should use .getMillis() if it works without .getMillis() with correct imports.

Comment: It is not an answer. You were merely *asking* the OP what he was doing. "Works for me" is also not an answer. It's true that the accepted answer is not the correct answer. But you need to first find out if the problem is the import **using the comments**, and *then* you can post an answer saying "You imported the wrong class, the class you imported doesn't have a public constructor" etc.

Comment: I posted my answer. Than 1 minute after that you posted your comment:

"@yasuo, edit your question, and write the full code including the import statements."

Comment: Now look at the comments to the OP and calculate when I posted my comment *there*. In any case, it isn't relevant: a question to the OP is **NOT AN ANSWER**.

Comment: It was just my format to help - start with question about details, but I have changed post. There are only answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96388/discussion-between-yuriy-tumakha-and-realskeptic).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Duration duration = new Duration(yesterday, today);
```

to

```
Duration duration = new Duration(yesterday.getMillis(), today.getMillis());
```

The [Duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) class has **no matching constructor** as the one your using. (`DateTime`, `DateTime`)

Comment: `DateTime` is a `ReadableInstant`.

Comment: I changed it. I have the same problem again.

Comment: DateTime today = new DateTime();        
      DateTime yesterday = today.minusDays(1);       
      
            long d1 = yesterday.getMillis();
            long d2 = today.getMillis();

            Duration duration = new Duration(d1, d2);

Comment: @yasuo, edit your question, and write the full code **including the import statements**.

Comment: Ok , I founded. I imported the wrong library. I used javax.xml.datatype.Duration instead of org.joda.time.Duration. :S

Comment: @yasuo You should not accept (mark with a checkmark) an answer that is not the correct answer. The problem was the import and not the constructor that you used. So unaccept it so that the author can delete it. Currently this question and answer are not useful for other people using Stack Overflow because of this.

Comment: @yasuo I agree with RealSkeptic. Second answer is correct.